# Texto sobre imagem responsivo

Tags: html, css, layout-responsivo, texto

consegui deixar uma imagem responsivo, mas a imagem tera q ter um texto por cima e eu nao consigo fazer com que o texto seja responsivo junto.
aqui esta meu codigo:

```css
h1 {
  font-family: sedgwick-ave;
  font-size: 5vw;
  position: absolute;
  left: 900px;
  bottom: 26vw;
}

.texx {
  font-family: FjallaOne-Regular;
  font-size: 1vw;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 705px;
  right: 340px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.texxt {
  font-family: FjallaOne-Regular;
  font-size: 1vw;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 600px;
  right: 310px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.foto {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 90%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="foto">
    <img src="imagens/biggie.jpg">
    </img>
    <h1>SOBRE</br> NÓS</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="texx">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,</br>
      sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna </br>
      aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation</br>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="texxt">
    <p> ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute indolo</br>
      Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore</br>
      eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident,sunt </br>
      in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Mas o que vc quer dizer com "texto responsivo"? Como vc quer que esse texto se comporte?

Comment: Quando eu diminuo a guia, a imagem fica no mesmo lugar, mas o texto que esta sobre ela nao, ele vai mais pra baixo, queria que ao diminuir a guia, o texto continuasse no mesmo lugar.

Comment: Fernanda vc poderia editar sua pergunta e incluir uma imagem do Layout que vc pretende?  Sem ofensas, é que o seu código não esta muito legal, esse valores de 700px 900px não são nada responsivos e são eles que estão quebrando seu layout, coloque uma imagem ai que ajuda a te responder, pq é praticamente impossível reaproveitar seu CSS, o ideal é refaze-lo do 0 já pensando na adaptação para outras telas

Comment: Precisa estudar melhor HTML. A tag `<img>` não se fecha com `</img>`. :))

Comment: Assim como `</br>` não existe